# How to link Requires to BuildRequires in rpm spec?

Tags: rpm

Let's say I have such `Requires` entries:

```
Requires: a
Requires: b
Requires: c
```

and now I would like to state, that:

```
BuildRequires: <<Requires>>
```

meaning, that for build I require everything that is required for install. So, if I remove or add something in the first section, I won't have to edit the second any more, because it will be "linked".

**The question is** -- how to express such dependency?

*I know that such scheme is not good for public packages, but I am asking for home use -- I prepare quick packages for me and my family only, they are not distributed.*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The easy answer is to define a macro which gets substituted into both locations.

```
%define my_common_requires package-1, package-2, package-3

BuildRequires: %{my_common_requires}
Requires:      %{my_common_requires}
```

This also lets you manually define something that needs to be in one of the two lines but not both.

Comment: From time to time it is embarrassing to see such "obvious" solution and miss it oneself ;-) Thanks a lot!

Comment: How to use this if packages have versions too? E.g. `package-1 = 1.0`

Comment: The same way:
`%define my_common_requires package-1 = 1.0, package-2 > 1.3, package-3`

Answer (score 5):

It seems, that

```
BuildRequires:  %{requires}
```

"just works" -- at least, on RHEL6, where RPM is of version 4.8.0

Answer (score 1):

Let

1. `P` be the name of your package;
2. `R1`, `R2`, ..., `Rn` be its Requires
3. `RB1`, `RB2`, ..., `RBm` be some its BuildRequires and `R1`, `R2`, ..., `Rn` be the other Requires.

Now you can

1. Create a package `PA` with Requires `R1`, `R2`, ..., `Rn` that is otherwise empty.
2. Edit `P` so that its Requires are `PA` and its BuildRequires are `PA`, `RB1`, `RB2`, ..., `RBm`

I am not convinced this is a good idea.

```
MyUsefulPackage
Requires: gcc
BuildRequires: gcc
```

becomes

```
MyUsefulPackage
Requires: MyUsefulRequires
BuildRequires: MyUsefulRequires
```

and

```
MyUsefulRequires
Requires: gcc
```

If I want to add another package `make` then it becomes:
    MyUsefulPackage
    Requires: MyUsefulRequires
    BuildRequires: MyUsefulRequires

and

```
MyUsefulRequires
Requires: gcc
Requires: make
```

It is not necessary to change the depends requirements of MyUsefulPackage.  I can make just one change to MyUsefulRequires.

Comment: No-go. Once you have one Rx more, you have to add RBx too. So you actually made situation worse than before -- not only requirements are not dynamically linked, but now I have to deal with 2 specs.

Comment: I don't think so.  I provided an example

Comment: OK, you are right about single point of dependency but as you said, "I am not convinced this is a good idea." and I can say that too ;-) So I will wait for exact solution.

Comment: I meant I don't think linking the dependencies is a good idea (consequently my answer is also not a good idea).  Is it really that hard to manually edit the spec file? What if you delete a Require dependency but it is still needed for the BuildRequire?

Comment: This was just example -- in fact I am linking in reverse, whatever is in BuildRequires I would like to be in Requires as well. Editing is not that hard, but easy to miss something, and after all -- why NOT ask? Maybe there is a solution and this way I will be set for a lifetime. And linking dependencies in **this particular** context is very good idea IMHO :-)